# Python Scrapy getting all as children but ignoring <br>

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I am trying to scrap data from webpage like

```
<div id="print">
  .
  .
  <div id="item">
    <div class="span3 col-3">
       Processor: 6th Gen. Intel Core i5 6200U
       <br>
       Clock speed: 2.30-2.80GHz
       <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
  .
  .
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use

```
for res in response.css('div#print'):
    text = res.css("div#item div.col-3::text").extract()
```

Output:

```
u'Processor:\xa07th Gen. Intel Core i5 7200U ', u'Clock speed:\xa02.50-3.10GHz '
```

I get 2 elements instead . How can I take whole text with `<br>` tag. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the output with <br> tag? or newline(\n) is enough?

Comment: Any of that will enough for me. I am just surprised why i am not getting whole text. why it divided in two items?

Answer (score 1):

You shall try by removing `::text` from the script

```
import html2text  # to convert HTML to text
for res in response.css('div#print'):
        text = res.css("div#item div.col-3").extract()  # removed ::text
print html2text.html2text(text[0])
```

Output:

```
Processor: 6th Gen. Intel Core i5 6200U  
Clock speed: 2.30-2.80GHz
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: It will be much appreciated if you accept the answer.